# Java Swing - Make a window like JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I've been creating **GUIs using Jigloo** for a game and I've run into a problem.

1. I would like one of my GUIs to have some properties that the **JOptionPane** has but I don't know how to describe it properly.
2. The **JOptionPane**, when open, doesn't allow a user to access the other open windows. It `gives a ping sound and flash the JOptionPane window`.
3. Is there a name for that? Also can I put that onto one of my GUI windows?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JOptionPane` uses a **modal** dialog.  See [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) for details.